# Using a Lens Flare on HDRP in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, game-development, post-processing

Is it possible to use Lens Flare on HDRP or LWRP? 
I tried to use the old lens flares but their shaders didn't work on HDRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the HDRP Lens Flare from Unity's Fontainebleau Demo (It includes a cs file, materials, and shaders for it), available on their official Github:

[Fontainebleau Github](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FontainebleauDemo)

Here at 52 seconds you can see it:

> https://youtu.be/hCeP_XUIB5U?t=52

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, if anyone still looking for HDRP Lens Flare, This guy is giving asset for totally free. Enjoy!

https://github.com/keijiro/Kino